# dynamic allocation in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am triing to save a .txt file into an object(c++). the problem is i dont know how big it is.

in c i would do it with a evl with the malloc() function but i have no idea how to do that in c++ or how to google that issue =/

Comment: Probably you are beginning with C++. What tutorials have you tried?

Comment: If you can do it in C, you can do it the same way in C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "save a .txt file into an object"? Do you mean that you want to read its contents into some sort of object? Or you want a reference to that file in memory? We'll need more details on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `std::ostringstream`?

Or if you want to use an equivalent to malloc, use:

```
char *storage = new char[__size__];

 ....

delete[] storage;
```

But if your file is a binary file odds are you have a byte which is null. `strlen` won't work the way you expect it then.

You can also use `std::string`, `std::vector<char>` in which you can have any values and that can be converted to `const char *` easily.

Answer (score 1):

why won't you save it as a string in a field of type std::string?
try:

```
myObj.someString = myFile.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `new` operator in C++, or better yet one of the [standard library containers](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/newdelete/50dynamalloc.html

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using standard containers than raw dynamic allocation